# Feed SQL Query Spreadsheet of Values and Output Value + Another Column

Tags: sql

Hoping someone can help me. It's been years since I've done SQL but I have a need now for it. I have a spreadsheet of serial numbers that I'd like to run through a database where I search for each serial number and then output the serial number and another column associated with that serial number. In this case the other column is "name."

So select Serial Number and Name from table where Serial Number = 
Then loop through until it gets to the end of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Plain sql is `SELECT number,name FROM table WHERE number = 42`. By the way: Which spreadsheet is using SQL syntax?